# R sample from mixture distribution

Tags: r, random

How could I sample from this distribution:

[image]

given:
() = ( = |~(/2)) , where (/2) is the Poisson distribution with lamda/2 and

(|) follows the chi square distribution with df=n+2y

Many thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? At present it looks like you're asking people to simply write solutions for you ...

Comment: Honestly, this site is full of  quetion asking for a solution without any trial, the thing here I think this is not a programming question so it seems do not belong to this site example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70726681/how-to-strip-periods-from-certain-words-but-not-the-of-sentences

Comment: The OP asked a question about this previously with the constraint that the solution had to use `runif()`, which made this sound like an exam question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with `n` degrees of freedom and non-centrality parameter `lambda`, so `rchisq(N, df=n, ncp=lambda)` should draw `N` samples from that distribution.

Comment: I cannot understand what is wrong with questions like this. I would have tried sth if I could. It is not an assignment per se. it has to do with my understanding on fundamental stats and simulation  and I believe it could be beneficial to others, too. But even if it was, I do not see anything wrong. honestly, what is the right place for such questions?

Comment: Asking about methods for sampling from a given distribution is probably on-topic for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). I think it would help if you gave some idea of the research effort you've put in, and some context for your question - otherwise it comes across as "please write some code for me"